# Convert Char to Double C++

Tags: c++, string-parsing

**UPDATE:**
I am passing a string variable and am iterating through the string character by character. Whenever I run into a decimal, I want to combine the previous position on the string (i.e. 2) and the next position in the string (i.e. 5) into a double. So how would I go about making the char 2, char . , char 5 into one whole double value (2.5)? Without using STL classes or Vectors. What I went ahead and tried was the following below. However, whenever I do the stuff in the var line, it doesn't hold the value 2.5 as a string. It holds a: "•". Is there something wrong that I am doing?

Comment: [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof).

Comment: You could also look into [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and using formatted input.

Comment: Parse you string using space as a delimiter, then use std::stod as mentioned by @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: How would you implement `std::stod` in this situation? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Lastly, `std::double`?

Comment: Start by writing a function "extract word under index", which takes string and index, and returns string containing the word under it. Rest should be trivial.

Comment: @Alakd You don't implement it, you call it

Answer (score 2):

If your point is to parse strings to doubles, I would take a different approach to iterate through the string. First, I would create an iterator splited by space to avoid checking if there is a '.'. And then I would iterate through this new iterator. Something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>


int main() {
    using namespace std;
    double num;
    string variableName = "4 5 7 2.5";
    istringstream iss(variableName);
    vector<string> nums{istream_iterator<string>{iss},
        istream_iterator<string>{}};
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        num = stod(nums[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it works regardless on how many characters are before and after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
double x;
std::string temp = "";
std::string variableName = "4 5 7 2.5";
std::string::size_type sz;     // alias of size_t
for (int i = 0; i < variableName.length(); i++) // iterates through variableName
{
    if (variableName[i] == '.') {
        temp += variableName[i - 1];
        temp += variableName[i];
        temp += variableName[i + 1];
        x = stod(temp, &sz);
    }
}
return x;
```

Comment: Going over your suggestion, wouldn't it crash as it reaches x? I attempted and debugged it, and it tells me "invalid stod argument".

Comment: You are correct- I've adjusted the code to resolve the exception.